# Config Export: How to store default value of taxonomy field?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, configuration

When I define a field with taxonomy term fields, I can set a default value depending on the available terms. Since the terms themselves are content, they are not stored via configuration management. When I export the configuration on one server (e.g. development) and import it into a different server (e.g. stage), these values may differ. Especially two terms with the same value on the servers don't necessarily share the same `tid`.

When I set a default value in dev, then this value's `tid` maybe not be the same as on the stage server and thus no default value or a wrong default value might be chosen, if I insert a new content of the type that has that field.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

The value stored in the config/sync is not the `tid` of the taxonomy term, but the `uuid`. Because of this, I can just change the value of `uuid` column in `taxonomy_term_data` row of the dev's term to that of the stage's server without affecting the `tid` column.

Comment: Something like [Content Serialization](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentserialize) might help with exporting the taxonomy terms and preserve their UUID's. You shouldn't need to hand update the UUID's then I think.

Comment: `This project is not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy.`